# Appending text + variable causes syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to include text, the append(), doesn't work. It causes a syntaxt error (Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list).

I don't get why this works:

```
$(".chatToInfo").append('<div class="green">' + peopleName + '</div>');`
```

But this doesn't:

```
$(".chatToInfo").append('<div class="green">'"Sending message to " + peopleName + '</div>');
```

Comment: try `$(".chatToInfo").append('<div class="green">"Sending message to "' + peopleName + '</div>');` . the problem might be this part `"green">'"` since you after `>` close the `'`. Or you can simply just add a `+` like `green">' + "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".chatToInfo").append('<div class="green">Sending message to' + peopleName + '</div>');
```

Comment: Please do not answer such typographical mistakes

Comment: Thanks. I thought I needed the " sign, since I was adding text. I learned something. So thanks for answering, even though it was a typographical mistake. But hey, even @Rajesh probably didn't know this at some point

Comment: @JonasSH first `didn't know` and not `didn't now`. Second, yes there was a time but I used to search google and check console for it and play around a lot first. Also not sure about the purpose of the comment. Still glad we were able to help you.

Comment: Yep I was missing a 'k', thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error. You are closing the opening quotes. That is what is causing the exception.

It should be

```
$(".chatToInfo").append('<div class="green">"Sending message to "' + peopleName + '</div>')
```

Comment: Please do not answer such typographical mistakes

Answer (score 1):

```
'<div class="green">'"Sending message to " + peopleName + '</div>'
```

this is unvalidated string.

the correct string below:

```
'<div class="green">"Sending message to "' + peopleName + '</div>'
```

Comment: Please do not answer such typographical mistakes. Also do check other answers before you post. Other answers have covered this already.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ES6`'s template literals``` (``) ``` which is much cleaner in this type of situation.

```js
var peopleName = 'John';
var el = `<div class="green">Sending message to ${peopleName}</div>`;
console.log(el);
$(".chatToInfo").append(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=".chatToInfo"></div>
```